# OOP PHP call to a member function on null

Tags: php, oop

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function passed() on null

but can't find mistake, I already looked at other posts and didn't find useful.

So I have 2 files, first register.php

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()){
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 3,
            'max' => 50
        )
    ));

    if($validation->passed()){
        echo 'Passed';
    }else{
        print_r($this->errors());
    }
}
```

?>

and second Validate.php

```
class Validate{

    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db = null;

    public function __construct(){
         $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
     }

    public function check($source, $items = array()){
        foreach($items as $item => $rules){
            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

                $value = $source[$item];

                if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)){
                    $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                }else{

                }
            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)){
            $this->_passed = true;
        }
    }

    private function addError($error){
        $this->_errors[] = $error;
    }

    public function errors(){
        $this->_errors;
    }

    public function passed(){
        return $this->_passed;
    }

}
```

It shows me error in first file in `if($validation->passed()){`

thanks for help

Comment: Your check method doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function `$validate->check` doesn't return anything, so your `$validation` stays null.
When you then call `$validation->passed()`, `$validation` is still null. Thats why the error says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function passed() on null

because you are trying to call function `passed` on `null`. 
What you probably intended to do is:

```
if(Input::exists()){
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 3,
            'max' => 50
        )
    ));

    if($validate->passed()){
        echo 'Passed';
    }else{
        print_r($validate->errors());
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, OP, you should simply change `$validation->passed()` to `$validate->passed()`.

Comment: And remove the unneccessary assignment to `$validation` and `$this`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if($validation->passed()){
```

with

```
if($validate->passed()){
```

And also replace

```
$this->errors()
```

with

```
$validate->errors()
```

As object of `Validate` class is `$validate` and **not** `$validation`.

Answer (score 0):

Your check() function should return something since it is not returning anything hence the NULL error.

To solve this add
`return $this;`
at the end of your check() function, so it would looks something like this.

```
    public function check($source, $items = array()){
    foreach($items as $item => $rules){
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

            $value = $source[$item];

            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)){
                $this->addError("{$item} is required");
            }else{

            }
        }
    }

    if(empty($this->_errors)){
        $this->_passed = true;
    }
  return $this;    //add this statement
}
```